# long click method to delete item from listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, onlongclicklistener

> could any one help me that how to perform long click option in list
>   view item's so i able to delete my notes from sq lite database ...i
>   have 2 column in my note app they are id ,title and notetext

my code to create table is ..

```
mydb1 = Main1Activity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("185", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

mydb1.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title varchar,notetext varchar);");
```

long click code

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        data.remove(arg2);
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: There is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846707/how-to-implement-a-long-click-listener-on-a-listview

Comment: @laalto oopps srry i edit it again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes i got the answer... it will be helpful for other stack flow user's :D :)

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>       
                                 (menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    Cursor cursor2=mydb1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM notes;", null);

    data.remove(arg2);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    cursor2.moveToPosition(arg2);
    int id= cursor2.getInt(cursor2.getColumnIndex("id"));

    mydb1.delete("notes", "id=?", new String[] {Integer.toString(id)});

    return true ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to implement OnLongClickListener to your items and do the query to delete from your BBDD...

[Android: Can't delete record from ListView and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102546/android-cant-delete-record-from-listview-and-sqlite)

Comment: hey please check my code once ..i update it again with long click code

Comment: 01-05 08:05:36.683: E/InputEventReceiver(1630): Exception dispatching input event.
01-05 08:05:36.683: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1630): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback

Comment: 01-05 10:56:37.115: E/AndroidRuntime(861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 10:56:37.115: E/AndroidRuntime(861):java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230724, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ArrayAdapter)]
01-05 10:56:37.115: E/AndroidRuntime(861):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1545)
01-05 10:56:37.115: E/AndroidRuntime(861):

Comment: when i try to add 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(); it gave me compile time error (adapter can not be resolved )